# rails 4.2.5 seems to be logging to standard out even though I didnt tell it to

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a production server (apache/passenger) I am pushing to using capistrano, in this one environment rails is logging to standard out instead of a file. I have searched to code base and I do not see anything that is making it go to standard out. Is there a config to say, log it to a file the default way...

I see the logs in the passenger.debug file that is how I know it is going to standard out. I have log file with proper permissions and passenger running as the same user, same exact setup works on our dev/staging server.

On my production server (the broken one)
from console:

```
Rails.logger
 => #<RailsStdoutLogging::StdoutLogger:0x0000000534b9d0
```

On my dev/staging server:

```
 Rails.logger
 => #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x00000006308878
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, this gem:

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

was doing this. I just moved off of heroku.